# Unable to display image label in second Tkinter frame

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple gui using Tkinter. The application involves a smaller secondary frame opening up over the primary one upon pressing a button. This secondary frame must contain an image. Image labels appear easily on the primary frame, but on the secondary frame, the image label appears as an empty box the size of the image, with whatever background colour I set.

[image: Here's what it looks like]

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
#send diagram page
def send_diagram():
    send_diagram_frame=tk.Frame(frame, bg="#D4BAEC")
    send_diagram_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.7, anchor="center")

    send_diagram_entry_working_image=Image.open('/home/raghav/RemEdi/design/assets/generic_page_entry.png')
    send_diagram_entry_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(send_diagram_entry_working_image)
    send_diagram_entry_label=tk.Label(send_diagram_frame, image=send_diagram_entry_image)
    send_diagram_entry_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
    return
```

As visible, send_diagram() is the command for the button.

I have tried adding another smaller frame inside the secondary frame to contain the image, but that did not work either.

Any help would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the new image inside a function, with it's own local namespace. When the function ends the reference to the image will be garbage collected.

You can fix this by saving a reference to the image in the Label widget. Put this line in the function after the image is created:

```
send_diagram_entry_label.image = send_diagram_entry_image
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and your answer got things working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code. I have try it and it's working for me.

```
def make_label_image(parent, img):
    label = tk.Label(parent, image=img)
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

def send_diagram():
    send_diagram_fram = tk.Frame(frame, bg="#D4BAEC")
    send_diagram_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relheight=0.7, relwidth=0.7, anchor="center")
    send_diagram_fram.pack_propagate(0)    
    send_diagram_fram.pack()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/logo.jpg')) 
    make_label_image(send_diagram_fram, img)
```